# AWS Greengrass installation on windows: "Cannot create all required directories"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot-greengrass

I'm trying to install Greengrass (V2) on my Windows computer (have to work with Windows, and can't use Docker because it is a Windows Enterprise license).
I followed the tutorial given in the Greengrass dashboard, meaning:

- I entered my access keys
- created the `ggc_user` (i can see it in the user management), saved the credentials with `psexec`
- downloaded the zip package and installed it with the provided cmd line

But it always returns the following error:

```
Error while trying to setup Greengrass Nucleus
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create all required directories
        at com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.KernelCommandLine.initPaths(KernelCommandLine.java:191)
        at com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.KernelCommandLine.lambda$parseArgs$0(KernelCommandLine.java:147)
        at com.aws.greengrass.config.Topic.subscribe(Topic.java:50)
        at com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.KernelCommandLine.parseArgs(KernelCommandLine.java:147)
        at com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.Kernel.parseArgs(Kernel.java:591)
        at com.aws.greengrass.easysetup.GreengrassSetup.performSetup(GreengrassSetup.java:296)
        at com.aws.greengrass.easysetup.GreengrassSetup.main(GreengrassSetup.java:269)
Caused by: java.nio.file.attribute.UserPrincipalNotFoundException
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsUserPrincipals.lookup(WindowsUserPrincipals.java:147)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem$LookupService$1.lookupPrincipalByGroupName(WindowsFileSystem.java:250)
        at com.aws.greengrass.util.platforms.windows.WindowsPlatform$WindowsFileSystemPermissionView.aclEntries(WindowsPlatform.java:413)
        at com.aws.greengrass.util.platforms.windows.WindowsPlatform$WindowsFileSystemPermissionView.<init>(WindowsPlatform.java:326)
        at com.aws.greengrass.util.platforms.windows.WindowsPlatform.getFileSystemPermissionView(WindowsPlatform.java:458)
        at com.aws.greengrass.util.platforms.Platform.setPermissions(Platform.java:167)
        at com.aws.greengrass.util.platforms.Platform.setPermissions(Platform.java:129)
        at com.aws.greengrass.util.Permissions.setRootPermission(Permissions.java:93)
        at com.aws.greengrass.util.NucleusPaths.setRootPath(NucleusPaths.java:99)
        at com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.KernelCommandLine.initPaths(KernelCommandLine.java:170)
        ... 6 more
```

I couldn't find anything usefull in the documentation.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you run the Greengrass command, are you using a cmd which is started as Administrator? You must run with Administrator rights to install Greengrass on Windows.
The error is that the group "Everyone" cannot be looked up. "Everyone" is a default group and should always exist on Windows. Does it exist for you?

Comment: Yes I started cmd as Administrator. Tried with Powershell as Administrator as well, same error. I'm located on the same directory I used to download the zip file (used the AWS provided command), which is `C:/Users/<my_user>/`.

Comment: The error is that the group "Everyone" cannot be looked up. "Everyone" is a default group and should always exist on Windows. Does it exist for you?

Comment: Yes it does, double-checked with our IT department. The computer is under a Workgroup, not a Domain, but tried with a Domain and failed as well.
Could it be because the computer is not set in English and somehow the user is a hardcoded string and not translated ?

Comment: Yes it does appear that the host language is an issue. If you're able to switch to English then it should work. This is something that Greengrass will need to address.

Comment: Ok so it worked for me, I created the group "Everyone" manually with the English syntax.
Thank you very much: could you upload an answer I can accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in Greengrass which means that it can only be used on English language systems right now.
We now have a pull request to fix it so it will work with any language.
https://github.com/aws-greengrass/aws-greengrass-nucleus/pull/1150

Comment: Following up, this fix was released in Nucleus version 2.5.5.